# Sort XML document based on grandchild

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

I have following XML and I want the "action" node to be in sorted order based on attribute value "no".

```
<game gamecode="10065904">
   <general>
      <startdate>2015-06-10 07:59:04</startdate>
      <players>
         <player seat="1" name="player1" chips="2,937" dealer="1" win="0" bet="20" rebuy="0" addon="0" reg_code="-" />
         <player seat="3" name="ponda22c" chips="780" dealer="0" win="0" bet="0" rebuy="0" addon="0" reg_code="-" />
         <player seat="5" name="Mesut1Rebel" chips="0" dealer="0" win="0" bet="0" rebuy="0" addon="0" reg_code="-" />
         <player seat="6" name="player4" chips="10,746" dealer="0" win="0" bet="420" rebuy="0" addon="0" reg_code="-" />
         <player seat="8" name="player5" chips="3,670" dealer="0" win="0" bet="420" rebuy="0" addon="0" reg_code="-" />
         <player seat="10" name="player6" chips="5,143" dealer="0" win="2,558" bet="1,700" rebuy="0" addon="0" reg_code="-" />
      </players>
   </general>
   <round no="0">
      <action no="1" player="player4" type="1" sum="10" cards="[cards]" />
      <action no="2" player="player5" type="2" sum="20" cards="[cards]" />
   </round>
   <round no="1">
      <cards type="Pocket" player="player1">X X</cards>
      <action no="4" player="player1" type="3" sum="20" cards="" />
      <cards type="Pocket" player="player4">X X</cards>
      <action no="5" player="player4" type="3" sum="10" cards="" />
      <cards type="Pocket" player="player5">X X</cards>
      <action no="6" player="player5" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <cards type="Pocket" player="player6">X X</cards>
      <action no="3" player="player6" type="3" sum="20" cards="" />
   </round>
   <round no="2">
      <cards type="Flop" player="">H4 CQ C8</cards>
      <action no="10" player="player1" type="0" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="7" player="player4" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="11" player="player4" type="3" sum="80" cards="" />
      <action no="8" player="player5" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="12" player="player5" type="3" sum="80" cards="" />
      <action no="9" player="player6" type="5" sum="80" cards="" />
   </round>
   <round no="3">
      <cards type="Turn" player="">H9</cards>
      <action no="13" player="player4" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="16" player="player4" type="3" sum="320" cards="" />
      <action no="14" player="player5" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="17" player="player5" type="3" sum="320" cards="" />
      <action no="15" player="player6" type="5" sum="320" cards="" />
   </round>
   <round no="4">
      <cards type="River" player="">HJ</cards>
      <action no="18" player="player4" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="21" player="player4" type="0" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="19" player="player5" type="4" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="22" player="player5" type="0" sum="0" cards="" />
      <action no="20" player="player6" type="5" sum="1,280" cards="" />
   </round>
</game>
```

For example in round no=2, action nodes are not in sequence, action no  7 is not the first child, its second over there. I want it to be first. So my sorted document's round no=2 should look as follows:

```
<round no="2">
  <cards type="Flop" player="">H4 CQ C8</cards> 
  <action no="7" player="player4" type="4" sum="0" cards="" /> 
  <action no="8" player="player5" type="4" sum="0" cards="" /> 
  <action no="9" player="player6" type="5" sum="80" cards="" /> 
  <action no="10" player="player1" type="0" sum="0" cards="" /> 
  <action no="11" player="player4" type="3" sum="80" cards="" /> 
  <action no="12" player="player5" type="3" sum="80" cards="" /> 
</round>
```

How can I do that using LINQ or by some other easy way. Note after the sorting only action nodes will change, other nodes will remain at same place.

Comment: It would help if you could reduce your sample XML to a more manageable size - enough to reproduce the issue, but no more - as well as indenting it appropriately but *without* the extraneous `-` characters which have presumably come from your browser.

Comment: "to be in sorted order" - how and where exactly?  Do you want to sort the XML in-place or when extracting a list of Actions?

Comment: What happens in the case that `cards` elements are interspersed throughout?  For example, how would you sort round 1?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have indented and I think I'll keep whole XML just to show other nodes of the document which should not be changed after the sort.

Comment: @CharlesMager Actually I'm parsing the xml line by line but the problem is actions are not in correct order i.e action no =2 is listed below action no 4. While parsing I want actions to be parsed number wise (first 2 then 4 etc). With regards to round 1 I'm ok with cards first and then actions.

Comment: You can show *some* nodes to give full context without it having to be nearly this long. Do you really need 9 attributes for each `player` element, just to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve? I suspect not. You should understand that a good question is clear of irrelevant distractions - this one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you don't mind if the actions are all grouped after the cards, you can parse this using LINQ to XML and remove all action elements and add them at the end in sorted order:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var round in doc.Descendants("round"))
{
    var sortedActions = round.Elements("action")
        .OrderBy(e => (int)e.Attribute("no"))
        .ToList();

    sortedActions.Remove();
    round.Add(sortedActions);
}
```

If you're already parsing the XML in your code as you imply, you may be able to simply sort these while reading each round.

Answer (score 1):

This should sort the action section of the xml as you want. The remove within the `Select()` is needed to disassociate the current unordered actions from the parent. Once that is done we add the ordered action back in.

```
static void Main()
{
    var root = XElement.Parse(xmlToParse);

    var orderedRoundElements= root.Elements("round")
                                .Select(element=>{
                                                var actions = element.Elements("action")
                                                                    .OrderBy(elem=> (int)elem.Attribute("no"))
                                                                    .ToList();
                                                actions.Remove();
                                                element.Add(actions);
                                                return element;
                                    }).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This also gave same results but second solution looks simple.